# Writing Dataset to an xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable

I have the following code to retrieve a dataset from a database. I would like to write this to an xml file. I have treied the following:

```
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    string filename = "tester";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        //get the dataset - THIS WORKS
        RetrieveData();

        //serialize data to a xml file
        dataset.WriteXml(filename + ".xml");
    }
```

I created a web aplication vs2010 and I cannot find where this file is being written..any ideas?

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its must be in your web application folder no where else....

or you can do is

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/fileExt.xml");
```

here upload is folder in you web application...

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked `ProjectFolder/bin/debug/tester.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
string filename = "c:\tester";
```